# In the ellipse-related formula $c^2=a^2-b^2$, is $a$ always the biggest number, or can it be the smallest?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Referring to Ellipses:

> In the formula $c^2= a^2-b^2$, is the $a$ always the biggest number or can it be the smallest?

Comment: A tag of (Education) is meant to be used for questions *about education*, the pedagogy of teaching or learning.  It is not meant to be used for a question that arose *during* your education.

Comment: We know that $c^2\geq0$.  What does that say about the relationship between $a^2$ and $b^2$?  By extension, what does that say about the relationship between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Now... notice that if $c^2 = a^2-b^2$, we have that $a^2 = c^2+b^2$.  In the event that all of these are positive, then yes $a\geq c$ since from $a^2=c^2+b^2\geq c^2$ and taking the square root of each side we arrive at $a\geq c$.  Similarly for $b$.  Now... if you allow for negative numbers, notice that with $a=-5,b=3,c=4$ you have $c^2=a^2-b^2$ is true as $4^2 = (-5)^2-3^2$, but $-5$ is obviously smaller than both $3$ and $4$ as it is the only negative number here.  As such, it is more correct to say that $a$ will have the largest *magnitude* or be the largest in absolute value.

Comment: If you drew an ellipse with two tacks, a string, and a pencil, how long would the string be [in terms of the parameters $a$ and $b$]? Now look at the ellipse when the pencil is on the minor axis, and try to calculate the focal length.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common, but distinct, conventions here.

---

One convention is that, whatever the length of the semi-major axis is, we call that $a$ (and the semi-minor axis $b$). The semi-major axis is the half the larger of the two axes of an ellipse, as seen in the following image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes):

[image: Ellipse with semi-major axis labeled 'a']

In an ellipse, the semi-major axis, $a$, is longer than the semi-minor axis, $b$, so under this convention $a$ is always the larger of the two numbers (if we define $a$ and $b$ this way, as lengths, we are assured both are positive).

---

The other convention is that we arbitrarily call the semi-major axis $a$ or $b$; in this situation, $a$ could be smaller than $b$. Or it could be bigger. We just don't know in advance.

In this case, we cannot use the equation $c^2 = a^2 - b^2$, because $|b|$ may well be larger, in which case $a^2 - b^2$ would be negative (but $c^2$ can't possibly be negative). So that equation for the focal length $c$ needs to be modified; instead we use 
$$c^2 = |a^2 - b^2|,$$
where the absolute value forces $|a^2 - b^2|$ to be positive, and all is well.

---

If your teacher/textbook are careful, and you see the equation $c^2 = a^2 - b^2$, then they must be following the first convention in which $|a|$ is larger than $|b|$.

But if you see the equation $c^2 = |a^2 - b^2|$, they are following the second convention and you don't know which of $|a|$ or $|b|$ is larger, in advance.

Comment: Thanks for that!